# Is it possible to intercept the call to non-existing function?

Tags: php

PHP has its magical methods `__call` and `__callStatic` which allow to intercept the calls to non-existing **methods**. I am looking for a way to intercept the call to non-existing **function** (the one that sits inside a namespace, not a type).

Is it possible to do (PHP7)?

*For a moment I considered putting functions inside proxy class, but namespace can span over several files, and if I am not mistaken, PHP does not have partial classes, thus this approach is of no use.*

Update: multiple files per namespace problem.

Let's say I have file A.php and B.php, both with the same namespace, say `Text`. Consider putting all the functions to proxy classes. And now I have file C.php and I have call `Text\indexOf(...)`. However I don't know if this is `Text\proxyA::indexOf` or `Text\proxyB::indexOf` because all information I have is name of the namespace -- `Text` -- and function name. So from caller side I am toasted.

Comment: If by "intercept" you mean "make the call resolve normally by returning a value of my own choosing" then no, it's not possible. But I am really curious -- what would the use case be?

Comment: @Jon, by intercept I mean exactly what `__callStatic` does with only one difference -- target is namespace not a type. The purpose, I am working on something similar to templates in C++, I would intercept a function call, demangle the name, and call function factory which produce (and then call) specialized version of the function (I use PHP as a backend for my language: http://aboutskila.wordpress.com/).

Comment: Well, if you need this feature then why are you compiling to direct function calls in the first place? You could instead compile to `resolve_function_call('mangled_name', ['argument', 'list'])` and problem solved. Or even replace bare function calls with static method calls on a type made especially for this purpose, that would intercept them with `__callStatic`.

Comment: @Jon, yes, this is what I am considering right now -- I am looking for interception, because it is what I use for template types already, so I would prefer to use the same mechanism (less code = less bugs). Of course if it is not possible I implement two separate ways for types and functions. As for static methods as functions in diguise I already wrote -- not possible, you can have multiple files per single namespace. Could you please post your last comment as a regular answer? Thank you.

Comment: @Jon, PS. there is also one downside more -- with interception&creation, you **create** a function and call subsequent calls are routed directly. With manual proxy all calls always go through such proxy -- so there is a slight overhead.

Comment: I'd like to understand the problem a little better before submitting an answer. How exactly does namespace-across-files prevent you from using a proxy class (a simple example would be great)?

Comment: Also, I had another idea. You could leverage autoloading together with the proxy class idea to achieve codegen-once-then-always-call-without-overhead. I made a PoC [here](http://ideone.com/4nLig7), perhaps that's closer to what you imagined?

Comment: @Jon, updated, and for a second approach I need a little time, I am not that good in PHP :-) But thank you tremendously for your help!

Comment: @Jon, except "%s" I think I understand everything :-) What's more I already checked that PHP is capable of calling magic functions in chain, so I could call non-existing method (instead of a function) on non-existing proxy class. The class will be created but instead of a method like in your example with `__callStatic` magic methods, which in turn will create a method **only once**. So on a subsequent call the class and the method will exist. Non-template functions will be put without a change, in namespace. So, please write an answer instead of a comment I will happily accept it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With PHP7+ you can catch calls to undefined functions:

```
try {
    not_exist();
} catch (\Error $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

You can then use `set_exception_handler` to catch that without it being in a `try`/`catch` block:

```
set_exception_handler(function($e) {
    echo '<BR>ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
});

not_exist();
```

Note that you need to use `set_exception_handler` and not `set_error_handler`.

Comment: Thank you, but you still would need to write try-catch, and worse with fake `catch` clause to avoid catching the exception. Since exceptions are expensive mechanism this does not add anything new really to the previous answer.

Comment: Why do you still need to write catch? What's fake catch?

Comment: "Sets the default exception handler if an exception is not caught within a try/catch block.". It means try-catch has to exist in the first place (otherwise program crashes), so I have to have try-catch only such it does not catch that exception.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be like you're saying, honestly.

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP7 you can catch undefined function calls:

```
try {
    idontexist();
} catch (\Error $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

There is no way to use this in the same way as `__call`, except of course through a custom error handler.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/j4WRB

Comment: Thank you, but in practice it is not really doable -- because you would have to wrap **every** function call in the try-catch, also you have to pay really attention to the exception and its stack -- it might be the case you call existing function, but this function call non-existing one which you forgot to wrap.

Comment: You are not wrong, but unfortunately that's all you get to work with.